# Setting default path in Github Actions `repository_dispatch`

Tags: github-actions

I have a repo containing E2E tests (and only tests) for several separate repos. These tests are activated using a Github Actions workflow on the repo, against applications hosted on a testing server.

There are 2 ways to trigger this workflow: `workflow_dispatch` so the workflow can be manually triggered on Github, and `repository_dispatch` so the workflow can be triggered from an external source.

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      TARGET_SUITE:
        default: 'application_A'
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [run-e2e]

jobs:
  # run the workflow
```

To run a specific suite of tests, I'm relying on the request body from `repository_dispatch`, i.e. { "target_suite" : "application_A" }

```
jobs:
...
- if: ${{ github.event.client_payload.target_suite == "application_A" }}
  # run test suite for application A
- if: ${{ github.event.client_payload.target_suite == "application_B" }}
  # run test suite for application B
```

However, if the workflow is triggered via Github, there would be no `client_payload`, and none of the tests would run.

How can I setup this workflow so it can accept triggers from either dispatch method? Hopefully not something like this:

```
- if: ${{ github.event.client_payload.target_suite == "application_A" }}
  # run application A
- if: ${{ github.event.client_payload.target_suite == "application_B" }}
  # run application B
- if: ${{ github.event.inputs.TARGET_SUITE == "application_A" }}
  # run application A
- if: ${{ github.event.inputs.TARGET_SUITE == "application_B" }}
  # run application B
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using two different types of events to trigger the workflow, then I don't think it is possible to have the same payloads.

I can think of two options:

- You could write some boilerplate that looks at the `client_payload` and `inputs` and sets the `target_suite` as an output. Subsequent steps could then just look at the output instead of looking at both the `inputs` and the `client_payload`
- Alternatively, unless there's a specific reason to trigger a `repository_dispatch`, you could also trigger a `workflow_dispatch` from the external source: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event